# Progress update in Parallel.For() loops

Tags: .net, parallel-extensions

As you can guess the index of the Parallel.For() loop jumps from one value to the other. How can I estimate the amount of the work done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By keeping a counter rather than looking at the index? For example:

```
int counter  = 0;
Parallel.For(4, 500, i => {
    // TODO: something useful...         
    int progress = Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", progress, i);
});
```

(the `Interlocked` usage is essential to avoid getting race-conditions on accessing `counter`)

Comment: And [here](https://gist.github.com/0xorial/8b82594e8f2b96beae77) is the same wrapped.

Answer (score 3):

```
int progress = 0;
Parallel.For( from, to, i => {
// do the job
Interlocked.Increment(ref progress);
});
```

now actual progress is `(float)(to - from) / progress`

Comment: No way to get this value without interfering with thread synchronization?

Comment: @devdept no. but what is the problem using this method?

Comment: I thought the the Parallel.For() included a more elegant way to get this value.

Comment: @devdept you have to add two lines of code, what is not elegant here?

Comment: @Alberto, [here](https://gist.github.com/0xorial/8b82594e8f2b96beae77) is a wrapper that incapsulates threading stuff. It is important to use value returned by 'Increment' though, otherwise you may still get race conditions.